# My Caps Lock is a Control Key, How Do I Restore to Caps Lock?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, capslock

In Vista, I had previously made my caps lock function as a control key, the problem is I don't know how to undo the change. I have searched around and most references I find mention changing the ScancodeMap in the registry but this isn't working for me (rebooted after and no change). I even tried the registry files available at [`http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_caps_lock/`](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_caps_lock/).

So, what other ways are there to make my caps lock act like a caps lock again?

Update: I've tried the following with no success:

- Removing scan code mappings with [`remove_scancode_mappings.reg`](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_caps_lock/remove_scancode_mappings.reg)
- Remapping Caps Lock to Caps Lock with [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/)

After each attempt, I have completely rebooted my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>[**SharpKeys**](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) should allow you to fix that, just map Caps Lock back to itself:</s>

[image]

<s>There is also [**AutoHotkey**](http://autohotkey.com):</s>

```
Capslock::Capslock
```

---

It seems it was a lower level problem. The key was mapped in the software that came with the keyboard.

Comment: I mapped Caps Lock to Caps Lock with this program and my caps lock is still a Control key. I'm stumped.

Comment: Looks like a job for autohotkey :)

Comment: AHK won't do it, I don't think. It relies on the keys not having been messed with. AHK is a better solution to the original problem, but not this one.

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling it was something lower level like a driver or something. If there is software you installed for your keyboard, check the settings you may have mapped something in there.

Comment: @John-T, if you make your previous comment an answer you get the points. I looked into the keyboard driver properties and in the upper filters, there is ctrl2cap listed. Thanks for the brain poke.

Comment: Glad to be of help, answer modified :)

Answer (score 1):

If your caps lock and control key are swapped with something other than scan code map, you could try also swapping them WITH scancode map.  The double swap should fix it.  Although I'm curious why you'd want to put it back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Realforce Keyboard (check your keyboard's brand for secret functions)

Fn + F11 swaps the ctrl and caps key functions

https://www.realforce.co.jp/en/features/fn-keys-fullsize.pdf